# pip3.7 install mysqlclient==1.3.13 fails with EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found

Tags: python, centos7, python-3.7, mysql-connector

While installing MySQL-client I am getting the error on the centos7 machine.
for the command, pip3.7 install mysqlclient==1.3.13. trying to resolve the issue based on some suggestions I tried yum install -y mysql-devel even on that I am getting the error can someone help where I was going wrong.

Error executing pip3.7 install mysqlclient==1.3.13

```
     command: /usr/local/bin/python3.7 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys                                                                                        .argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-50arat2r/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"                                                                                        '"'/tmp/pip-install-50arat2r/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'                                                                                        open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f                                                                                        .close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp                                                                                        /pip-pip-egg-info-_n2uh5pv
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-50arat2r/mysqlclient/
    Complete output (10 lines):
    /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-50arat2r/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 18, in <module                                                                                        >
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-50arat2r/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 53, in g                                                                                        et_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "/tmp/pip-install-50arat2r/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 28, in m                                                                                        ysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    OSError: mysql_config not found
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output
```

Error executing yum install -y mysql-devel

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mariadb-devel.x86_64 1:5.5.65-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.65-1.el7 for package: 1:mariadb-devel-5.5.65-1.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mariadb-libs.x86_64 1:5.5.65-1.el7 will be installed
Removing mariadb-libs.x86_64 1:5.5.65-1.el7 - u due to obsoletes from installed mysql-community-libs-8.0.22-1.el7.x86_64
--> Restarting Dependency Resolution with new changes.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mariadb-libs.x86_64 1:5.5.65-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.65-1.el7 for package: 1:mariadb-devel-5.5.65-1.el7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 1:mariadb-devel-5.5.65-1.el7.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.65-1.el7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: That's better suited as a bug report. If you wanted to turn it into a programming question, you'd have to extract and provide a [mcve]. However, I guess you don't want to work on that software but with that software.

Comment: facing same error